# SetInterval says function does not exist

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't know what I am missing here. When the setInterval starts to run it says the function does not exist. I know it is there ( I did not include the variables...as that is not the issue). Any idea on why I am getting an error saying the functions don't exist?

```
function midgroundFunc() {
    $('#midground').css({
        backgroundPosition: '0px 0px'
    });
    $('#midground').animate({
        backgroundPosition: "(" + midX + " " + midY + ")"
    }, midTime, midEase);
}

function foregroundFunc() {
    $('#foreground').css({
        backgroundPosition: '0px 0px'
    });
    $('#foreground').animate({
        backgroundPosition: "(" + foreX + " " + foreY + ")"
    }, foreTime, foreEase);
}

function backgroundFunc() {
    $('#back').css({
        backgroundPosition: '0px 0px'
    });
    $('#back').animate({
        backgroundPosition: "(" + backX + " " + backY + ")"
    }, backTime, backEase);
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#midground').css({
        backgroundImage: 'url(' + midImage + ')'
    });
    $('#foreground').css({
        backgroundImage: 'url(' + foreImage + ')'
    });
    $('#back').css({
        backgroundImage: 'url(' + backImage + ')'
    });
    $.backstretch(backgroundStretch);



    midgroundFunc();
    foregroundFunc();
    backgroundFunc();

    setInterval("midgroundFunc()", midTime);
    setInterval("foregroundFunc()", foreTime);
    setInterval("backgroundFunc()", backTime);

});
```

This is the error I am getting:

Error: backgroundFunc is not defined
Line: 96

Error: midgroundFunc is not defined
Line: 94

Error: foregroundFunc is not defined
Line: 95

Comment: SetInterval is global, and cannot see your function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the functions directly instead of using a string.  That way you avoid the scoping issue:

```
 setInterval(midgroundFunc, midTime);
 setInterval(foregroundFunc, foreTime);
 setInterval(backgroundFunc, backTime);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you supply a *string* to `setInterval`, it will evaluate this string in the global context when its time has come. If the functions it's supposed to call aren't global, it won't be able to call them.

```
(function () {
    function callMe() { }

    setInterval("callMe()", 1000);
})();

// "callMe()" will be evaluated here,
// where function callMe is not in scope
```

Pass a *reference to the callback function*, not a string:

```
setInterval(callMe, 1000);
```